# Developed android app working fine through USB connected Physical Device but the same .apk file not working in other devices

Tags: java, android, sqlite, launching-application

New to android development, but developed the android app. It's working fine through USB connected mobile device from the Android Studio IDE!.
Everything successful,  now generated .apk and installed into other device to test it but not launching!..

My app has connected SQLite DB to store and retrieve some data, all these working fine through USB connected devices! But not launching other devices.

I tried to create a very simple app just with text view and it's. Apk working in other devices!
I tried Toast message in onCreate method in MainActivity, it's popping up in USB connected physical device but not launching and no toast message popping up in other devices.

I want, it should work in other devices also like in my mobile device used to connect in Android Studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.